# How can I put text in many different activities as efficiently as possible in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Noobish question but how can I write a lot of text in different activities in Android Studio (Java)? Basically, what I have to do is make 9 layouts and write more than **200** pieces of (separate) text which the user can cycle between by pressing buttons. Each piece of text will be shown on top of one of the 9 layouts.

How do I go about doing that? I thought about writing the text as strings and then put it into an arraylist, but then I'd have to add every separate string into the list and the code would get abysmally long.  I've also thought about using fragments, but I don't quite know how to use them and I don't really want 200 fragments in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you add constant Strings as resources anyways?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. But how exactly should I proceed after doing so?

Comment: See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray) for information on interacting with String Arrays.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about this, my bad. Thank you!